# Swift 4 decode complex nested JSON

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm trying to create a cleaner codable structure in which I can access the "description" by just typing `day.description` rather than `day.weather.description`

The description value is nested in an array "weather" which only contains a single object. I would like to extract the description from the index 0 and assign it to description in my struct.

Here is the JSON that I'm working with:

```py
{
    "dt": 1558321200,
    "main": {
        "temp": 11.88,
        "temp_min": 11.88,
        "temp_max": 11.88,
        "pressure": 1013.3,
        "sea_level": 1013.3,
        "grnd_level": 1003.36,
        "humidity": 77,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 5.58,
        "deg": 275.601
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2019-05-20 03:00:00"
}
```

and the code I have so far:

```py
struct Weather: Codable {
    let days: [Day]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case days = "list"
    }
}

struct Day: Codable {
    let date: String
    let main: Main
    let wind: Wind
    let description: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "dt_txt"
        case main
        case wind
        case weather
        case description
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        main = try container.decode(Main.self, forKey: .main)
        wind = try container.decode(Wind.self, forKey: .wind)
        let weather = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .weather)
        description = try weather.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a computed property to your struct that returns description from the first element of the weather array?

Comment: Yes, I was going to suggest the same thing.

Comment: In future, please don't ask a question about decoding JSON and then fail to show the _real_ JSON you are actually faced with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've been told, the simplest approach is just a computed property that references the desired value. However, for the sake of completeness we might as well discuss how to do the thing you actually asked to do. Let's illustrate with a reduced version of your JSON:

```
{
  "dt": 1558321200,
  "weather": [{
    "id": 800,
    "main": "Clear",
    "description": "clear sky",
    "icon": "01n"
  }]
}
```

So the question is, how can we parse this into, say, a struct Result with a `description` property such that we fetch out the `"description"` key from the first item in the `"weather"` array? Here's one approach:

```
struct Result : Decodable {
    let description : String
    enum Keys : CodingKey {
        case weather
    }
    struct Weather : Decodable {
        let description : String
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let con = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
        var arr = try! con.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .weather) // weather array
        let oneWeather = try! arr.decode(Weather.self) // decode first element
        self.description = oneWeather.description
    }
}
```

Basically the idea here is that `nestedUnkeyedContainer` gives us our array, and subsequent calls to `decode` on that array automatically tackle each element in turn. We have only one element so we need only one `decode` call. How we dispose of the resulting string is up to us, so now we can slot it into our top-level `description` property.

But here's another approach. We don't even really need the secondary Weather struct; we can just dive right into the `"weather"` array and grab the first dictionary element and access its `"description"` key without saying any more about what's in that inner dictionary, like this:

```
struct Result : Decodable {
    let description : String
    enum Keys : CodingKey {
        case weather
        case description
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let con = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
        var arr = try! con.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .weather)
        let con2 = try! arr.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Keys.self)
        let desc = try! con2.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
        self.description = desc
    }
}
```

Your question was not very complete (you didn't show your *real* JSON, just an excerpt), so I can't give any more precise advice, but I'm sure you can see how adapt this technique to your needs.